# What is the extra data specified in a DNS entry called?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

A Windows DNS server can have extra data specified in it's DNS entry to alert certain machines of the location of specific types of servers...for instance an entry might have a some of this data that specifies:

- To a machine to be ghosted where the Fog server is
- Specify to an Allworx Handset where the Allworx server is,
- Or specify to a Windows KMS workstation with a generic key where the KMS server is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're referring to [location of service records (SRV)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt).  They're not Windows DNS specific.

With Powershell, you can retrieve them from your AD Domain easily.

```
Import-Module DnsServer
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -RRType SRV -ZoneName $(Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot -ComputerName $(Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
```

Comment: Thanks because "Are they Windows DNS specific?" was going to be my next question.